# SocketCAN stops read after RX overflow, is it normal?

Tags: sockets, can-bus, socketcan

I’m doing tests on embedded hardware with integrated CAN bus interface.
The driver provides Linux Socket API.

I try to see the limits:
I have one transmitter that writes CAN frames as fast as possible and a receiver that reads continuously.

After a moment the receiver gets an error frame signalling RX overflow.
I have no problem with that, it's normal and expected.

But my question is why at this point no more frame is received ?
(The restart-ms option is set)

I expected some dropped frames and others RX buffer errors but not the end of reception.

Answer (score 1):

After exchanging emails with *socket-can* developers and my device provider, it was an bug in the driver.
In the mean time a patch was released to move at91_can to new *rx_fifo* architecture.
[this patch fix the issue](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/mkl/linux-can-next.git/commit/?h=at91-next&id=7234e9dee7d0df75de7ae14443a2306435750594).